# JavaScript Span to Input

Tags: javascript

I'm dealing with a situation in my web site needs where I'd like for a user to be able to click on some text (surrounded by `<span>`) and have it turn into an input box, then back to plain text after editing or lose focus.

I found tons of stuff everywhere but none of it is really working!

The very same working jsfiddle is not working in my actual webpage. So here is the code to my page, I'd like for someone to explain to me why it's not working and help me fix it.

```html
<html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('span').live('click', function() {
      var input = $('<input />', {
        'type': 'text',
        'name': 'aname',
        'value': $(this).html()
      });
      $(this).parent().append(input);
      $(this).remove();
      input.focus();
    });

    $('input').live('blur', function() {
      $(this).parent().append($('<span />').html($(this).val()));
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });
</script>

<style>
  body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  
  .box {
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 1px;
  }
  
  .rotated {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  
  table {
    empty-cells: show;
    padding: 0px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  
  .padd {
    padding: 0px;
  }
  
  .padding {
    padding: 0px;
  }
</style>



<body>
  <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 40%;">

    Currently Viewing.
    <div style=" width: 100%; display: flex;
         border-bottom: 1px; border-bottom-color: black; border-bottom-style:solid;">
      <div style="width: 25%;">Date:</div>
      <div style="width: 25%;">asdasdasd</div>
      <div style="width: 25%;">Client: </div>
      <div style="width: 25%;">asdsd</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div style=" width: 100%; display: flex;
             border-bottom: 1px; border-bottom-color: black; border-bottom-style:solid;">
        <div style="width: 25%;">Style #:</div>
        <div style="width: 25%;">asdasdasd</div>
        <div style="width: 25%;">Season / Year: </div>
        <div style="width: 25%;">asdsd</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div style=" width: 100%; display: flex;
                border-bottom: 1px; border-bottom-color: black; border-bottom-style:solid;">
        <div style="width: 25%;">Size Range:</div>
        <div style="width: 25%;">asdasdasd</div>
        <div style="width: 25%;"> Preparation/Thread: </div>
        <div style="width: 25%;">asdsd</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div style=" width: 100%; display: flex;
                border-bottom: 1px; border-bottom-color: black; border-bottom-style:solid;">
        <div style="width: 25%;">Sample Size:</div>
        <div style="width: 25%;">asdasdasd</div>
        <div style="width: 25%;">Description: </div>
        <div style="width: 25%;"> asdsd</div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <br> Before....

    <span>
                  test
               </span>


    <br>
    <table class="padding box" style=" width: 100%;border: 1px; border-style: solid; padding: 0px;  table-layout: fixed; border-collapse: collapse;">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">

        </td>
        <td class="box">
          Tol
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          XS
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          S
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          M
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          L
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          XL
        </td>
      </tr>
      <br>
      <tr style="height: 10px;" class="padding box">
        <td class="box padding rotated" style="width: 15%; vertical-align: middle; word-wrap:break-word; height: 200px;" rowspan="2">BODY</td>
        <td>
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>

        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td>
          test
        </td>


      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 10px;" class="padding box">

        <td>
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>

        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td>
          test
        </td>


      </tr>

      </tr>
    </table>

    <br> After...
    <br>
    <table class="padding box" style=" width: 100%;border: 1px; border-style: solid; padding: 0px;  table-layout: fixed; border-collapse: collapse;">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">

        </td>
        <td class="box">
          Tol
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          XS
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          S
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          M
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          L
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          XL
        </td>
      </tr>
      <br>
      <tr style="height: 10px;" class="padding box">
        <td class="box padding rotated" style="width: 15%; vertical-align: middle; word-wrap:break-word; height: 200px;" rowspan="2">BODY</td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td class="box padding">

        </td>

        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td>
          test
        </td>


      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 10px;" class="padding box">

        <td>
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>

        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td>
          test
        </td>


      </tr>

      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>



  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to get this part to turn into a textbox

```
  <br>
    Before....

        <span>
              test
           </span>


    <br>
```

Comment: Why not use the `content-editable` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## FIRST

html is not even close to valid. BR tags cannot be inside of TABLE. you have extra closing tags all over the place, and things that should be in HEAD are just laying about in the html (style and script tags)

## SECOND AND MORE IMPORTANT

you are trying to add events to elements that do not exist. when you put your script tags at the top of the body, the JS wil be ran before the body is done.

This becomes especially important because instead of delegating your events properly, you are instead attaching a new event listener to every single span tag

https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

## THIRD

MVCE is very important on StackOverflow. Don't include your ENTIRE html page when your question is only about a single span tag. I cleaned up your html for you so you have a working "copy and pastable" solution. however your question SHOULD only have the html that is relevant to your issue

https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

## THE FIX

1. runtime:

   a. put the JS at the bottom of the body where it's supposed to go

   b. wrap your JS in `$(function(){})`
2. event delegation

   All events here should be delegated to a common parent:
   `$(document).on('click', 'span', function(){})`
3. `live` is deprecated and you should not use it.

   you should ALWAYS read the docs for any library you use BEFORE you start using it

```js
$(function () {
  $(document).on('click', 'span', function () {
  console.log(this)
    var input = $('<input />', {'type': 'text', 'value': $(this).text().trim()});
    $(this).replaceWith(input);
    input.focus();
  });
  
  $(document).on('blur', 'input', function () {
    var val = $(this).val(),
       span = $('<span />');
    span.html(val)
    $(this).replaceWith(span);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  
}
.cell {
  width: 100%; display: flex; border-bottom: 1px; border-bottom-color: black; border-bottom-style:solid;
 }
.box {
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 1px;
}
.rotated {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
table { 
  empty-cells: show;
  padding: 0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.padd {
  padding: 0px;
}
.padding {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 40%;">
  
  Currently Viewing.
  <div class="cell">
    <div style="width: 25%;">Date:</div>
    <div style="width: 25%;" >asdasdasd</div>
    <div style="width: 25%;">Client: </div>
    <div style="width: 25%;">asdsd</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div style="width: 25%;">Style #:</div>
    <div style="width: 25%;">asdasdasd</div>
    <div style="width: 25%;">Season / Year: </div>
    <div style="width: 25%;">asdsd</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div  style="width: 25%;">Size Range:</div>
    <div style="width: 25%;">asdasdasd</div>
    <div style="width: 25%;"> Preparation/Thread: </div>
    <div style="width: 25%;">asdsd</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div style="width: 25%;">Sample Size:</div>
    <div style="width: 25%;" >asdasdasd</div>
    <div style="width: 25%;">Description: </div>
    <div style="width: 25%;"> asdsd</div>
  </div>
  
  
  <br>
  Before....
  
  <span>
    test
  </span>
  
  
  <br>
  <table class="padding box" style=" width: 100%;border: 1px; border-style: solid; padding: 0px;  table-layout: fixed; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          
        </td>
        <td class="box" >
          Tol
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          XS
        </td>
        <td  class="box">
          S
        </td>
        <td class="box" >
          M
        </td>
        <td class="box" >
          L
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          XL
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr style="height: 10px;" class="padding box">
        <td class="box padding rotated" style="width: 15%; vertical-align: middle; word-wrap:break-word; height: 200px;" rowspan="2" >BODY</td>
        <td>
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td>
          test
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 10px;" class="padding box">
        <td>
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td>
          test
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
  <br>
  After...
  <br>
  <table class="padding box" style=" width: 100%;border: 1px; border-style: solid; padding: 0px;  table-layout: fixed; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <thead>
      <tr >
        <td colspan="3">
          
        </td>
        <td class="box" >
          Tol
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          XS
        </td>
        <td  class="box">
          S
        </td>
        <td class="box" >
          M
        </td>
        <td class="box" >
          L
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          XL
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr style="height: 10px;" class="padding box">
        <td class="box padding rotated" style="width: 15%; vertical-align: middle; word-wrap:break-word; height: 200px;" rowspan="2" >BODY</td>
        <td>
          
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          
        </td>
        
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td>
          test
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 10px;" class="padding box">
        
        <td>
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td>
          test
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `.live()` to `.on()` as `.live()` is deprecated function.

Below is working code:

```html
<html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('span').on('click', function() {
      var input = $('<input />', {
        'type': 'text',
        'name': 'aname',
        'value': $(this).html()
      });
      $("#container").append(input);
      $("#testSpan").remove();
      input.focus();
    });

    $('input').on('blur', function() {
      $(this).parent().append($('<span />').html($(this).val()));
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });
</script>

<style>
  body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  
  .box {
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 1px;
  }
  
  .rotated {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  
  table {
    empty-cells: show;
    padding: 0px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  
  .padd {
    padding: 0px;
  }
  
  .padding {
    padding: 0px;
  }
</style>



<body>
  <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 40%;">

    Currently Viewing.
    <div style=" width: 100%; display: flex;
         border-bottom: 1px; border-bottom-color: black; border-bottom-style:solid;">
      <div style="width: 25%;">Date:</div>
      <div style="width: 25%;">asdasdasd</div>
      <div style="width: 25%;">Client: </div>
      <div style="width: 25%;">asdsd</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div style=" width: 100%; display: flex;
             border-bottom: 1px; border-bottom-color: black; border-bottom-style:solid;">
        <div style="width: 25%;">Style #:</div>
        <div style="width: 25%;">asdasdasd</div>
        <div style="width: 25%;">Season / Year: </div>
        <div style="width: 25%;">asdsd</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div style=" width: 100%; display: flex;
                border-bottom: 1px; border-bottom-color: black; border-bottom-style:solid;">
        <div style="width: 25%;">Size Range:</div>
        <div style="width: 25%;">asdasdasd</div>
        <div style="width: 25%;"> Preparation/Thread: </div>
        <div style="width: 25%;">asdsd</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div style=" width: 100%; display: flex;
                border-bottom: 1px; border-bottom-color: black; border-bottom-style:solid;">
        <div style="width: 25%;">Sample Size:</div>
        <div style="width: 25%;">asdasdasd</div>
        <div style="width: 25%;">Description: </div>
        <div style="width: 25%;"> asdsd</div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <br> Before....
<div id="container">
    <span id="testSpan">test</span>
    </div>


    <br>
    <table class="padding box" style=" width: 100%;border: 1px; border-style: solid; padding: 0px;  table-layout: fixed; border-collapse: collapse;">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">

        </td>
        <td class="box">
          Tol
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          XS
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          S
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          M
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          L
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          XL
        </td>
      </tr>
      <br>
      <tr style="height: 10px;" class="padding box">
        <td class="box padding rotated" style="width: 15%; vertical-align: middle; word-wrap:break-word; height: 200px;" rowspan="2">BODY</td>
        <td>
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>

        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td>
          test
        </td>


      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 10px;" class="padding box">

        <td>
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>

        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td>
          test
        </td>


      </tr>

      </tr>
    </table>

    <br> After...
    <br>
    <table class="padding box" style=" width: 100%;border: 1px; border-style: solid; padding: 0px;  table-layout: fixed; border-collapse: collapse;">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">

        </td>
        <td class="box">
          Tol
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          XS
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          S
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          M
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          L
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          XL
        </td>
      </tr>
      <br>
      <tr style="height: 10px;" class="padding box">
        <td class="box padding rotated" style="width: 15%; vertical-align: middle; word-wrap:break-word; height: 200px;" rowspan="2">BODY</td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td class="box padding">

        </td>

        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td>
          test
        </td>


      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 10px;" class="padding box">

        <td>
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>

        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td>
          test
        </td>


      </tr>

      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>



  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Click on the "test" you'll see that it puts the textbox at the bottom of the page, not in the place of the text..

Comment: @digit check my code now. Updated answer. Rest you can change the CSS etc as per your requirement.

Comment: Awsome! can you update the code so it goes back to span after edit / unfocus?

Comment: @digit that was not part of the requirement in your question.

Comment: $('input').on('blur', function() {
      $(this).parent().append($('<span />').html($(this).val()));
      $(this).remove();
    });  ---- this is in my code, it's not working though... it was one of the things i tried mentioning but seemed to have forgotten. why doesn't this one work?

Comment: @digit see my answer for more explanations on what you need to change and why

Answer (score 1):

`.live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed entirely in 1.9. You are using 3.3.1, so you should be using `.on()` instead.

Comment: Well.... ok, that makes sense. But my entire function doesn't work right now. can you show me a JSFiddle with .on() being used?

Comment: @digit well for one your html is not valid

Answer (score 0):

If you run the stack snippet you'll see an error saying `$(...).live is not a function`. It was removed back in v1.9.

You have to create your own event delegation using `on()`

```html
<html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'span', function() {
      var input = $('<input />', {
        'type': 'text',
        'name': 'aname',
        'value': $(this).html()
      });
      $(this).after(input);
      $(this).remove();
      input.focus();
    });

    $(document).on('blur', 'input', function() {
      $(this).after($('<span />').html($(this).val()));
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });
</script>

<style>
  body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  
  .box {
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 1px;
  }
  
  .rotated {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  
  table {
    empty-cells: show;
    padding: 0px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  
  .padd {
    padding: 0px;
  }
  
  .padding {
    padding: 0px;
  }
</style>



<body>
  <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 40%;">

    Currently Viewing.
    <div style=" width: 100%; display: flex;
         border-bottom: 1px; border-bottom-color: black; border-bottom-style:solid;">
      <div style="width: 25%;">Date:</div>
      <div style="width: 25%;">asdasdasd</div>
      <div style="width: 25%;">Client: </div>
      <div style="width: 25%;">asdsd</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div style=" width: 100%; display: flex;
             border-bottom: 1px; border-bottom-color: black; border-bottom-style:solid;">
        <div style="width: 25%;">Style #:</div>
        <div style="width: 25%;">asdasdasd</div>
        <div style="width: 25%;">Season / Year: </div>
        <div style="width: 25%;">asdsd</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div style=" width: 100%; display: flex;
                border-bottom: 1px; border-bottom-color: black; border-bottom-style:solid;">
        <div style="width: 25%;">Size Range:</div>
        <div style="width: 25%;">asdasdasd</div>
        <div style="width: 25%;"> Preparation/Thread: </div>
        <div style="width: 25%;">asdsd</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div style=" width: 100%; display: flex;
                border-bottom: 1px; border-bottom-color: black; border-bottom-style:solid;">
        <div style="width: 25%;">Sample Size:</div>
        <div style="width: 25%;">asdasdasd</div>
        <div style="width: 25%;">Description: </div>
        <div style="width: 25%;"> asdsd</div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <br> Before....

    <span>
                  test
               </span>


    <br>
    <table class="padding box" style=" width: 100%;border: 1px; border-style: solid; padding: 0px;  table-layout: fixed; border-collapse: collapse;">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">

        </td>
        <td class="box">
          Tol
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          XS
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          S
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          M
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          L
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          XL
        </td>
      </tr>
      <br>
      <tr style="height: 10px;" class="padding box">
        <td class="box padding rotated" style="width: 15%; vertical-align: middle; word-wrap:break-word; height: 200px;" rowspan="2">BODY</td>
        <td>
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>

        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td>
          test
        </td>


      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 10px;" class="padding box">

        <td>
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>

        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td>
          test
        </td>


      </tr>

      </tr>
    </table>

    <br> After...
    <br>
    <table class="padding box" style=" width: 100%;border: 1px; border-style: solid; padding: 0px;  table-layout: fixed; border-collapse: collapse;">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">

        </td>
        <td class="box">
          Tol
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          XS
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          S
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          M
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          L
        </td>
        <td class="box">
          XL
        </td>
      </tr>
      <br>
      <tr style="height: 10px;" class="padding box">
        <td class="box padding rotated" style="width: 15%; vertical-align: middle; word-wrap:break-word; height: 200px;" rowspan="2">BODY</td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td class="box padding">

        </td>

        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td>
          test
        </td>


      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 10px;" class="padding box">

        <td>
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>

        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td class="box padding">
          test
        </td>
        <td>
          test
        </td>


      </tr>

      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>



  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you click on the "test" text you'll see the textbox gets put at the bottom of the page not in its place

Comment: I didn't know that was an issue, you can use `after` instead of `append` in that case.